# Netherlands Schengen visa rejected; what can I do?

Tags: schengen, spain, netherlands, tourist-visas, visa-rejections

I applied to the Netherlands for a Schengen visa, and was refused. I showed hotel bookings for 14 days in the Netherlands, since I didn't have a confirmed itinerary when I applied.

The reason for refusal states:

> Sufficient justification for the purpose and circumstances of the intended stay was not provided and the intention to leave the territory of member states cannot be ascertained.

I have two options now: appeal or apply from another country. As of now, I plan to spend the most days of the trip in Spain, so should I apply at the Spanish Embassy?

Would it be a problem, applying to Spain, after the refusal. My flight tickets are to and from Amsterdam, although most of the time would be in Spain.

Comment: what do you mean by _Showed hotel bookings for 14 days in nederlands as was not confirmed about the itenary at time of applying_? And **yes** you should apply through Spain since you're spending more time there.

Comment: I would say that you should apply to Spain, but that wouldn't be correct because, in fact, you *must* apply to Spain.  It is necessary to apply to the country that is your main destination.  Be careful, though: it might look like forum shopping.  If you can, you should explain why you changed your plans.

Answer (score 0):

The Schengen visa system, like many other visa systems, is supposed to let *genuine* tourists and business travelers in and to keep *illegal* immigrants out. The note said

> the intention to leave the territory of member states cannot be ascertained

That means they think you *might* want to immigrate, and it is up to your application to answer their doubts.

- A typical tourist has a well-paid, *steady* job to pay for the vacation.
- A typical tourist has ties to the home country which make it likely that he or she will return. That could be a well-paid, *steady* job, or real estate, or a business, or something like that.

This is **much** more important than a hotel booking, or having enough money in your bank account. I fear that unless you get this problem solved, an appeal or another application won't help.